# How to unhighlight symbol highlighted with highlight-symbol-at-point

Tags: highlighting

`highlight-symbol-at-point` is really useful however I could not find an easy way to un-highlight symbols.

Currently I have to call `unhighlight-regexp` repeatedly for each highlighted symbol.

Is there a better way to:

- unhighlight all highlighted symbols in a buffer
- unhighlight a symbol at point?

Comment: Do you need to unhighlight all symbols in one go?

Comment: Most of the time - yes. Occasionally unhighlighting a symbol at point is useful as well.

Comment: The answers would be different if you want to unhighlight the symbol under point or unhighlight all symbols.

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: You can remove all highlighted symbols using `M-x hi-lock-mode`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Is there a better way to unhighlight all highlighted symbols in a buffer?

From `C-h f unhighlight-regexp`, we get

> (unhighlight-regexp REGEXP)
>
> Remove highlighting of each match to REGEXP set by hi-lock.
>   Interactively, prompt for REGEXP, accepting only regexps
>   previously inserted by hi-lock interactive functions.
>   If REGEXP is t (or if C-u was specified interactively),
>   then remove all hi-lock highlighting.

That means that we simply need to call `unhighlight-regexp` with `t` as its argument to remove all hi-lock highlighting in the buffer.

If it were a one-time thing, it could be quickly done by `M-: (unhighlight-regexp t)` or `C-u M-s h u`. But it seems that this is something you need to do quite often. In that case, it's better to wrap it in an `interactive` function and bind it to some key.

Below is a proposed solution where `my/unhighlight-all-in-buffer` is the wrapper interactive function and it is bound to `hU` in the `search-map`. By default the `search-map` prefix is `M-s`. So now, just as `M-s h u` launches `unhighlight-regexp`, `M-s h U` (note the capital U) launches `my/unhighlight-all-in-buffer`.

```el
(require 'hi-lock)        
(defun my/unhighlight-all-in-buffer ()
  "Remove all highlights made by `hi-lock' from the current buffer.
The same result can also be be achieved by \\[universal-argument] \\[unhighlight-regexp]."
  (interactive)
  (unhighlight-regexp t))
(define-key search-map "hU" #'my/unhighlight-all-in-buffer)
```

---

### Is there a better way to unhighlight a symbol at point?

The good thing is that you do not need to place the point on a symbol you need to unhighlight.

You simply call `M-x unhighlight-regexp` or `M-s h u` (its default binding) and hit `M-p`/`M-n` till you come across the regexp of the symbol you need to unhighlight, and hit Enter.

Answer (score 10):

`C-u C-x w r`

> `(unhighlight-regexp REGEXP)`
>   (...) If REGEXP is t (or if `C-u`
>   was specified interactively), then remove all hi-lock highlighting.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use library [**Highlight**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) ([`highlight.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el)), commands `hlt-highlight-symbol-at-point` and `hlt-unhighlight-symbol-at-point`.

They are bound default to `C-x X h s` and `C-x X u s`, respectively.  All of the highlighting and unhighlighting commands are bound on prefix key **`C-x X`** by default.  Highlighting commands use prefix key **`C-x X h`**.  Unhighlighting commands use prefix key **`C-x X u`**.  You can use a different prefix key than `C-x X` by just binding it to prefix command `hlt-map`.

Highlighting in library Highlight can use overlays or text properties (or both). The highlighting face or color can be chosen automatically (from a customized sequence of faces and colors) or not.

Highlighting can use property `font-lock-face`, so that it is controlled by Font Lock mode.  Or it can use property `face`, so that it is not controlled by it. (You can use property `face` to highlight in buffers that do not use font-lock, and the highlighting remains in font-locked buffers when you turn off Font Lock mode.)

Answer (score 1):

This will unhighlight a single symbol:

```
(defun unhighlight-symbol-at-point ()
  "Remove highlight of symbol at point."
  (interactive)
  (unhighlight-regexp (concat "\\_<" (thing-at-point 'symbol) "\\_>")))
```